# Removing and modifying items from ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have put up a snippet of my MVC4 code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5a27/7/). I would like the "minus" button to remove the row it belongs to, then goes through the array and adjust the input names to be sequential. I think I will need it to be sequential to work with MVC4 model binding.

My problem is, how do I identify which button has just been clicked, and which object in the array it belongs to? Any ideas please? I'm completely new to knockout so I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do it.

This is my viewmodel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.breeders = ko.observableArray([{
        keyName: ko.observable("Breeders[0].Key"),
        valueName: ko.observable("Breeders[0].Value"),
        canAdd: ko.observable(true),
        canRemove: ko.observable(true)
    }]);

    this.addRow = function () {
        var next = this.breeders().length;
        this.breeders.push({
            keyName: ko.observable("Breeders[" + next.toString() + "].Key"),
            valueName: ko.observable("Breeders[" + next.toString() + "].Value"),
            canAdd: ko.observable(true),
            canRemove: ko.observable(true)
        });
    };

    this.removeRow = function () {

    };
}
```

And this is my markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="breedersFormsContainer" data-bind="template: {name: 'breederForm', foreach: breeders}"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="breederForm">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-3">
        <span class="col-lg-1 control-label">Reg: </span><span class="col-lg-2"><input data-bind="attr: {name: keyName}" type="text" class="form-control" /></span>
        <span class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name: </span><span class="col-lg-6"><input data-bind="attr: {name: valueName}" type="text" class="form-control" /></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="enable: canRemove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="enable: canAdd, click: $parent.addRow.bind($parent)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span></button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bound the click handler to the button, you can do the following

```
this.removeRow = function (data) {
    yourObservableArray.remove(data);
    };
```

data will be a reference to the object bound to the current row

Comment: I assume that will work if the action is defined in the object, but it's not. The `removeRow` function is in the `$parent`. Please refer to the jsFiddle snippet.

Comment: @DanyW this solution should work even if you have the `removeRow` on the `$parent` becuase KO passes the "current" item automatically into a click handler as the first parameter see here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fMAKB/

Comment: Ach... it does work indeed. I copied'n'pasted the binding code and forgot to change `addRow` to `removeRow`.